# data extraction from dictionary

Tags: python

I want to extract the data from my dictionary. I wrote the following code

```
subarray = {
   'Chr1': data[data[:,0] == 'chr1'],
   'Chr2': data[data[:,0] == 'chr2']
}
for the_key, the_value in subarray.iteritems():
   cnt = len(subarray)
   for i in range(cnt): 
       lst = the_value[i]
       chr_name = lst[0]
       first_cord = lst[1]
       second_cord = lst[2]
```

I am not able to extract the whole data form the list in the dictionary but getting only 23 data points.  Also I am getting the following error

```
IndexError: index 19 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 19
```

Comment: You take the length of the dictionary, but index into the value list. You probably meant `cnt = len(the_value)`. And since you don't need `i`, you can simply `for lst in the_value:`. If you need the index use `enumerate()`. **And**: what is `data` and why do you index it by the result of a comparison?

Comment: and it's a dictionary in a tuple

Comment: @minitoto Nope, it's just brackets around the dictionary literal. There's no `,` at the end. But you need to scroll for that.

Comment: Hi actually data is the ndarray to which i have read my file